# use shell execute to run cmd as Admin

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I need to run cmd on a button click as admin. It works. but I need to run it as an admin. How is this done?

```
 ShellExecute(Handle, 'open', 'c:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe', nil, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL)
```

Answer (score 28):

Replace the `open` verb with the `runas` as shown below. Anyway, try to avoid path hardcoding:

```
uses
  ShellAPI;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShellExecute(Handle, 'runas', 'cmd.exe', nil, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
end;
```

You can also add to your button the shield icon by setting the [`ElevationRequired`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TButton.ElevationRequired) property to True.

Comment: Why is this answer not accepted? So easy simple and works.

Answer (score 14):

`ShellExecute/Ex()` with the `"runas"` verb is the only *official* way to start an elevated process programmably, especially if the executable being run does not have its own UAC manifest to invoke elevation.

However, that is not the *only* way to start an elevated process.  Have a look at the following article, which explains elevation in detail and offers alternative implementations, like `CreateProcessElevated()` and `ShellExecuteElevated()`, which are more flexible:

[Vista UAC: The Definitive Guide](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19165/Vista-UAC-The-Definitive-Guide)

Answer (score 8):

This is sample code to use ShellExecute + runas to run routines elevated (i.e. under full administrator account). It should work with both UAC enabled/disabled + in older Windows versions (before Windows Vista).

```
unit RunElevatedSupport;

{$WARN SYMBOL_PLATFORM OFF}
{$R+}

interface

uses
  Windows;

type
  TElevatedProc        = function(const AParameters: String): Cardinal;
  TProcessMessagesMeth = procedure of object;

var
  // Warning: this function will be executed in external process.
  // Do not use any global variables inside this routine!
  // Use only supplied AParameters.
  OnElevateProc: TElevatedProc;

// Call this routine after you have assigned OnElevateProc
procedure CheckForElevatedTask;

// Runs OnElevateProc under full administrator rights
function RunElevated(const AParameters: String; const AWnd: HWND = 0; const AProcessMessages: TProcessMessagesMeth = nil): Cardinal; overload;

function  IsAdministrator: Boolean;
function  IsAdministratorAccount: Boolean;
function  IsUACEnabled: Boolean;
function  IsElevated: Boolean;
procedure SetButtonElevated(const AButtonHandle: THandle);


implementation

uses
  SysUtils, Registry, ShellAPI, ComObj;

const
  RunElevatedTaskSwitch = '0CC5C50CB7D643B68CB900BF000FFFD5'; // some unique value, just a GUID with removed '[', ']', and '-'

function CheckTokenMembership(TokenHandle: THANDLE; SidToCheck: Pointer; var IsMember: BOOL): BOOL; stdcall; external advapi32 name 'CheckTokenMembership';

function RunElevated(const AParameters: String; const AWnd: HWND = 0; const AProcessMessages: TProcessMessagesMeth = nil): Cardinal; overload;
var
  SEI: TShellExecuteInfo;
  Host: String;
  Args: String;
begin
  Assert(Assigned(OnElevateProc), 'OnElevateProc must be assigned before calling RunElevated');

  if IsElevated then
  begin
    if Assigned(OnElevateProc) then
      Result := OnElevateProc(AParameters)
    else
      Result := ERROR_PROC_NOT_FOUND;
    Exit;
  end;


  Host := ParamStr(0);
  Args := Format('/%s %s', [RunElevatedTaskSwitch, AParameters]);

  FillChar(SEI, SizeOf(SEI), 0);
  SEI.cbSize := SizeOf(SEI);
  SEI.fMask := SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
  {$IFDEF UNICODE}
  SEI.fMask := SEI.fMask or SEE_MASK_UNICODE;
  {$ENDIF}
  SEI.Wnd := AWnd;
  SEI.lpVerb := 'runas';
  SEI.lpFile := PChar(Host);
  SEI.lpParameters := PChar(Args);
  SEI.nShow := SW_NORMAL;

  if not ShellExecuteEx(@SEI) then
   RaiseLastOSError;
  try

    Result := ERROR_GEN_FAILURE;
    if Assigned(AProcessMessages) then
    begin
      repeat
        if not GetExitCodeProcess(SEI.hProcess, Result) then
          Result := ERROR_GEN_FAILURE;
        AProcessMessages;
      until Result <> STILL_ACTIVE;
    end
    else
    begin
      if WaitForSingleObject(SEI.hProcess, INFINITE) <> WAIT_OBJECT_0 then
        if not GetExitCodeProcess(SEI.hProcess, Result) then
          Result := ERROR_GEN_FAILURE;
    end;

  finally
    CloseHandle(SEI.hProcess);
  end;
end;

function IsAdministrator: Boolean;
var
  psidAdmin: Pointer;
  B: BOOL;
const
  SECURITY_NT_AUTHORITY: TSidIdentifierAuthority = (Value: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5));
  SECURITY_BUILTIN_DOMAIN_RID  = $00000020;
  DOMAIN_ALIAS_RID_ADMINS      = $00000220;
  SE_GROUP_USE_FOR_DENY_ONLY  = $00000010;
begin
  psidAdmin := nil;
  try
    // Создаём SID группы админов для проверки
    Win32Check(AllocateAndInitializeSid(SECURITY_NT_AUTHORITY, 2,
      SECURITY_BUILTIN_DOMAIN_RID, DOMAIN_ALIAS_RID_ADMINS, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
      psidAdmin));

    // Проверяем, входим ли мы в группу админов (с учётов всех проверок на disabled SID)
    if CheckTokenMembership(0, psidAdmin, B) then
      Result := B
    else
      Result := False;
  finally
    if psidAdmin <> nil then
      FreeSid(psidAdmin);
  end;
end;

{$R-}

function IsAdministratorAccount: Boolean;
var
  psidAdmin: Pointer;
  Token: THandle;
  Count: DWORD;
  TokenInfo: PTokenGroups;
  HaveToken: Boolean;
  I: Integer;
const
  SECURITY_NT_AUTHORITY: TSidIdentifierAuthority = (Value: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5));
  SECURITY_BUILTIN_DOMAIN_RID  = $00000020;
  DOMAIN_ALIAS_RID_ADMINS      = $00000220;
  SE_GROUP_USE_FOR_DENY_ONLY  = $00000010;
begin
  Result := Win32Platform <> VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_NT;
  if Result then
    Exit;

  psidAdmin := nil;
  TokenInfo := nil;
  HaveToken := False;
  try
    Token := 0;
    HaveToken := OpenThreadToken(GetCurrentThread, TOKEN_QUERY, True, Token);
    if (not HaveToken) and (GetLastError = ERROR_NO_TOKEN) then
      HaveToken := OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess, TOKEN_QUERY, Token);
    if HaveToken then
    begin
      Win32Check(AllocateAndInitializeSid(SECURITY_NT_AUTHORITY, 2,
        SECURITY_BUILTIN_DOMAIN_RID, DOMAIN_ALIAS_RID_ADMINS, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        psidAdmin));
      if GetTokenInformation(Token, TokenGroups, nil, 0, Count) or
         (GetLastError <> ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER) then
        RaiseLastOSError;
      TokenInfo := PTokenGroups(AllocMem(Count));
      Win32Check(GetTokenInformation(Token, TokenGroups, TokenInfo, Count, Count));
      for I := 0 to TokenInfo^.GroupCount - 1 do
      begin
        Result := EqualSid(psidAdmin, TokenInfo^.Groups[I].Sid);
        if Result then
          Break;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    if TokenInfo <> nil then
      FreeMem(TokenInfo);
    if HaveToken then
      CloseHandle(Token);
    if psidAdmin <> nil then
      FreeSid(psidAdmin);
  end;
end;

{$R+}

function IsUACEnabled: Boolean;
var
  Reg: TRegistry;
begin
  Result := CheckWin32Version(6, 0);
  if Result then
  begin
    Reg := TRegistry.Create(KEY_READ);
    try
      Reg.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
      if Reg.OpenKey('\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System', False) then
        if Reg.ValueExists('EnableLUA') then
          Result := (Reg.ReadInteger('EnableLUA') <> 0)
        else
          Result := False
      else
        Result := False;
    finally
      FreeAndNil(Reg);
    end;
  end;
end;

function IsElevated: Boolean;
const
  TokenElevation = TTokenInformationClass(20);
type
  TOKEN_ELEVATION = record
    TokenIsElevated: DWORD;
  end;
var
  TokenHandle: THandle;
  ResultLength: Cardinal;
  ATokenElevation: TOKEN_ELEVATION;
  HaveToken: Boolean;
begin
  if CheckWin32Version(6, 0) then
  begin
    TokenHandle := 0;
    HaveToken := OpenThreadToken(GetCurrentThread, TOKEN_QUERY, True, TokenHandle);
    if (not HaveToken) and (GetLastError = ERROR_NO_TOKEN) then
      HaveToken := OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess, TOKEN_QUERY, TokenHandle);
    if HaveToken then
    begin
      try
        ResultLength := 0;
        if GetTokenInformation(TokenHandle, TokenElevation, @ATokenElevation, SizeOf(ATokenElevation), ResultLength) then
          Result := ATokenElevation.TokenIsElevated <> 0
        else
          Result := False;
      finally
        CloseHandle(TokenHandle);
      end;
    end
    else
      Result := False;
  end
  else
    Result := IsAdministrator;
end;

procedure SetButtonElevated(const AButtonHandle: THandle);
const
  BCM_SETSHIELD = $160C;
var
  Required: BOOL;
begin
  if not CheckWin32Version(6, 0) then
    Exit;
  if IsElevated then
    Exit;

  Required := True;
  SendMessage(AButtonHandle, BCM_SETSHIELD, 0, LPARAM(Required));
end;

procedure CheckForElevatedTask;

  function GetArgsForElevatedTask: String;

    function PrepareParam(const ParamNo: Integer): String;
    begin
      Result := ParamStr(ParamNo);
      if Pos(' ', Result) > 0 then
        Result := AnsiQuotedStr(Result, '"');
    end;

  var
    X: Integer;
  begin
    Result := '';
    for X := 1 to ParamCount do
    begin
      if (AnsiUpperCase(ParamStr(X)) = ('/' + RunElevatedTaskSwitch)) or
         (AnsiUpperCase(ParamStr(X)) = ('-' + RunElevatedTaskSwitch)) then
        Continue;

      Result := Result + PrepareParam(X) + ' ';
    end;

    Result := Trim(Result);
  end;

var
  ExitCode: Cardinal;
begin
  if not FindCmdLineSwitch(RunElevatedTaskSwitch) then
    Exit;

  ExitCode := ERROR_GEN_FAILURE;
  try
    if not IsElevated then
      ExitCode := ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED
    else
    if Assigned(OnElevateProc) then
      ExitCode := OnElevateProc(GetArgsForElevatedTask)
    else
      ExitCode := ERROR_PROC_NOT_FOUND;
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      if E is EAbort then
        ExitCode := ERROR_CANCELLED
      else
      if E is EOleSysError then
        ExitCode := Cardinal(EOleSysError(E).ErrorCode)
      else
      if E is EOSError then
      else
        ExitCode := ERROR_GEN_FAILURE;
    end;
  end;

  if ExitCode = STILL_ACTIVE then
    ExitCode := ERROR_GEN_FAILURE;
  TerminateProcess(GetCurrentProcess, ExitCode);
end;

end.
```

---

Usage:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows{....};

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    Label3: TLabel;
    Label4: TLabel;
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure StartWait;
    procedure EndWait;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

uses
  RunElevatedSupport;

{$R *.dfm}

const
  ArgInstallUpdate     = '/install_update';
  ArgRegisterExtension = '/register_global_file_associations';

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Label1.Caption := Format('IsAdministrator: %s',        [BoolToStr(IsAdministrator, True)]);
  Label2.Caption := Format('IsAdministratorAccount: %s', [BoolToStr(IsAdministratorAccount, True)]);
  Label3.Caption := Format('IsUACEnabled: %s',           [BoolToStr(IsUACEnabled, True)]);
  Label4.Caption := Format('IsElevated: %s',             [BoolToStr(IsElevated, True)]);

  Button1.Caption := 'Install updates';
  SetButtonElevated(Button1.Handle);
  Button2.Caption := 'Register file associations for all users';
  SetButtonElevated(Button2.Handle);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  StartWait;
  try
    SetLastError(RunElevated(ArgInstallUpdate, Handle, Application.ProcessMessages));
    if GetLastError <> ERROR_SUCCESS then
      RaiseLastOSError;
  finally
    EndWait;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  StartWait;
  try
    SetLastError(RunElevated(ArgRegisterExtension, Handle, Application.ProcessMessages));
    if GetLastError <> ERROR_SUCCESS then
      RaiseLastOSError;
  finally
    EndWait;
  end;
end;

function DoElevatedTask(const AParameters: String): Cardinal;

  procedure InstallUpdate;
  var
    Msg: String;
  begin
    Msg := 'Hello from InstallUpdate!' + sLineBreak +
           sLineBreak +
           'This function is running elevated under full administrator rights.' + sLineBreak +
           'This means that you have write-access to Program Files folder and you''re able to overwrite files (e.g. install updates).' + sLineBreak +
           'However, note that your executable is still running.' + sLineBreak +
           sLineBreak +
           'IsAdministrator: '        + BoolToStr(IsAdministrator, True) + sLineBreak +
           'IsAdministratorAccount: ' + BoolToStr(IsAdministratorAccount, True) + sLineBreak +
           'IsUACEnabled: '           + BoolToStr(IsUACEnabled, True) + sLineBreak +
           'IsElevated: '             + BoolToStr(IsElevated, True);
    MessageBox(0, PChar(Msg), 'Hello from InstallUpdate!', MB_OK or MB_ICONINFORMATION);
  end;

  procedure RegisterExtension;
  var
    Msg: String;
  begin
    Msg := 'Hello from RegisterExtension!' + sLineBreak +
           sLineBreak +
           'This function is running elevated under full administrator rights.' + sLineBreak +
           'This means that you have write-access to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE key and you''re able to write keys and values (e.g. register file extensions globally/for all users).' + sLineBreak +
           'However, note that this is usually not a good idea. It is better to register your file extensions under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes.' + sLineBreak +
           sLineBreak +
           'IsAdministrator: '        + BoolToStr(IsAdministrator, True) + sLineBreak +
           'IsAdministratorAccount: ' + BoolToStr(IsAdministratorAccount, True) + sLineBreak +
           'IsUACEnabled: '           + BoolToStr(IsUACEnabled, True) + sLineBreak +
           'IsElevated: '             + BoolToStr(IsElevated, True);
    MessageBox(0, PChar(Msg), 'Hello from RegisterExtension!', MB_OK or MB_ICONINFORMATION);
  end;

begin
  Result := ERROR_SUCCESS;
  if AParameters = ArgInstallUpdate then
    InstallUpdate
  else
  if AParameters = ArgRegisterExtension then
    RegisterExtension
  else
    Result := ERROR_GEN_FAILURE;
end;

procedure TForm1.StartWait;
begin
  Cursor := crHourglass;
  Screen.Cursor := crHourglass;
  Button1.Enabled := False;
  Button2.Enabled := False;
  Application.ProcessMessages;
end;

procedure TForm1.EndWait;
begin
  Cursor := crDefault;
  Screen.Cursor := crDefault;
  Button1.Enabled := True;
  Button2.Enabled := True;
  Application.ProcessMessages;
end;

initialization
  OnElevateProc := DoElevatedTask;
  CheckForElevatedTask;

end.
```

Comment: I like this one. The uses clause needs to be "Windows, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.StdCtrls, System.Classes,Forms,System.SysUtils".

Answer (score 0):

```
uses ShellApi, ...;

function RunAsAdmin(const Handle: Hwnd; const Path, Params: string): Boolean;
var
  sei: TShellExecuteInfoA;
begin
  FillChar(sei, SizeOf(sei), 0);
  sei.cbSize := SizeOf(sei);
  sei.Wnd := Handle;
  sei.fMask := SEE_MASK_FLAG_DDEWAIT or SEE_MASK_FLAG_NO_UI;
  sei.lpVerb := 'runas';
  sei.lpFile := PAnsiChar(Path);
  sei.lpParameters := PAnsiChar(Params);
  sei.nShow := SW_SHOWNORMAL;
  Result := ShellExecuteExA(@sei);
end;
```

// Example

```
RunAsAdmin(Handle, 'c:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe', '');
```