# Copy files using windows credentials

Tags: delphi

I need to copy some files to **Program files**  folder using Delphi. I know it can simply do with `CopyFile()` function easily if that user have access to program files folder. But if that user has no access to program files  I need to do it with a specific user (some function can pass parameters of user and password and copy files ). How can I do this?

Comment: That's the wrong approach because it won't get round UAC. Add the requireAdministrator option to your manifest.

Comment: If you want to manipulate files/subfolders in "Program files" you must manifest your program as "requireAdministrator". This, in turn, means that only users with adimistrator credentials can run your program. If you want standard users to use your program, stop manipulating "Program files", so you can omit "requireAdministrator" from the manifest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know you can't without starting a new process with elevated rights.
So you should either create a second app which does the copying and start that with elevated rights or restart your own app with elevated rights.

How to do that is shown in many places in stackoverflow, e.g. here:
[use shell execute to run cmd as Admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15319158/use-shell-execute-to-run-cmd-as-admin).

Comment: What about impersonation, will that work? [Ask the User for Credentials](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms717794.aspx), then [`LogonUser()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184.aspx) and [`ImpersonateLoggedOnUser()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378612.aspx), then finally `CopyFile()`.

Comment: I cannot really proof, but I doubt that an app can etevate its own privilige without being restarted (or starting another process with elevated rights). Even system tools tike Sysinternals Autoruns tool is doing it that way. And Sysinternals belongs to Microsoft, so they should know how to do it...