# Possible to open a PowerShell (run as Administrator) from Delphi?

Tags: powershell, delphi, delphi-7

I want to open Powershell as an administrator (no problem if prompt for UAC to elevate) when i click to a button in Delphi.

Is it possible?

Thank you

Comment: yes, of course!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be easier ways, but this one works.
Create a CMD/BAT file a write this:

```
@echo off
if not "%1"=="am_admin" (powershell start -verb runas '%0' am_admin & exit /b)
cd
@cd /d "%~dp0"
cd
powershell.exe
```

Save and execute it with Delphi using ShellExecute:

```
ShellExecute(Handle, 'open', PChar('r:\PowerShellUAC.bat'), nil, nil, SW_NORMAL);
```

Comment: Never use `ShellExecute` because it can't report errors properly. Use `ShellExecuteEx`. But after that, why are we using a bat file for this. Why not pass the verb `runas` directly to `ShellExecuteEx` with the path to the powershell executable and any arguments that you want.

Comment: See here for a solution: [use shell execute to run cmd as Admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15319158/use-shell-execute-to-run-cmd-as-admin). Just replace "cmd.exe" in the examples with "powershell.exe". There is an example using "ShellExecuteEx" as well.

Comment: It is common practice nowadays to disable the execution of batch files via GPO - so this should not be the accepted answer at all. As for how to run some application as administrator - there are already answers to this question on SO.